# Light cones and reference frames

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, inertial-frames

I'd like to know what does it mean exactly to find a reference frame in which two events occur at the same time or in the same space coordinates. As I picture it if we have two events A and B in a (x, y, t) space we would need to find, for each case, a "tilted" frame x' y' t'in which:
a) the two events are in the x'y' plane, so that they have the same t' coordinate  and
b) the two events are in the time axis, so that they have equal x' and y' coordinates.

The problem with this picture is that I can't see why we can't find a frame like the one on case a) if the interval is spacelike nor one like in case b) if the events are timelike. I understand the physycal meaning of it (more or less) but I'd like to know if there is also any mathematical/geometrical explanation of why is no possible to find this frames.

Comment: Excluding the case of a light-like event interval, the event interval is space-like or time-like, the "or" here being exclusive. For space-like intervals, one may choose a frame where the time difference is zero, and for time-like intervals, one may choose a frame where the spatial difference is zero.

Comment: I know that. My question was how would these frames "look like".

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "look like" ? You have to apply (in $3+1$ dimensions) transformations  of the Lorentz group ([boosts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_transformation), rotations, or a combination of them) to go from one frame to another frame. So, your job is just to find the correct transformation of the Lorentz group, which transform your $\Delta x, \Delta y, \Delta z, \Delta t$ in the way you want.

Comment: Suposing a (2 + 1)-dimensional space we can draw a cone that delimits spacetime intervals and timelike intervals. I am curious about how these transformations would be represented on that (2 + 1)-dimensional space.

Comment: Try  this : If you consider the possible values of $\Delta x, \Delta y, \Delta t$ in differents coordinate systems, you will have [hyperboloids](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperboloid) (just replace $z$ - the vertical coordinate -  by $t$ in the beginning of the Wiki article). For a space-like interval, you have a one-sheet hyperboloid, and for a time-like interval, you have a 2-sheet hyperboloid.

Comment: Let me reword my question: what stops us from choosing a frame in which two events separated by a timelike interval have the same or reversed order? What is the constraint that forbids us to do so that does not apply on events separated by spacelike intervals?

Comment: For a time-like interval, with any change of frame, you are stuck in the upper (or the lower) sheet of the 2-sheet [hyperboloid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperboloid). But  you  cannot go from the upper sheet to the lower sheet.